# Check if a float has a specified amount of digits and decimal places

Tags: python

I want to check if a float has a specified amount of digits and decimal places.

Specifically, I want to check if an input has five digits followed by exactly one decimal place

E.g 54321.4

I've tried looking into Regexp but I wanted to see if there was a simpler solution first.

```
# I've started with the below code

def getNum():
    num = float(input('Enter number with 5 digits and 1 decimal place:'))

    while not len(str(abs(num))) == 5:
      print('Error: Number must have exactly five digits followed by one 
      decimal place.\n')
      num = float(input('Enter number with 5 digits and 1 decimal place:'))

    return num

print(getNum())
```

For example, if an input of 123 was passed into the getNum function, it should keep prompting the user to enter again until the user enters a number with five digits and exactly one decimal place after the fifth digit.

Comment: You shouldn't try to convert it to a number and back, this will change the "amount of decimal places". You can use regex, or you can `split()` it on `'.'` and see what pieces you get.

Comment: You should check it while you still have the decimal string. Checking it as a float isn't possible, as there are no decimal digits in a float, only binary digits, and they aren't commensurable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, regex **is** the simplest solution – no need to shy away from it.

```
import re

# Explanation:
#   ^      start of string
#   \d{5}  5 digits
#   \.     literal period
#   \d     digit
#   $      end of string
rgx = re.compile(r'^\d{5}\.\d$')

tests = [
    '12345.6',
    'hi',
    '12345.67',
]

for s in tests:
    m = rgx.search(s)
    print(bool(m), s)
```

Output:

```
True 12345.6
False hi
False 12345.67
```